# Is there any way to include Adobe AIR to an application for iOS?

Tags: ios, air

When you trying to install an AIR-app for the first time on an iDevice, you get this message about you need to install Adobe AIR first. Is there any way to avoid this? I mean to build the app somehow so, that it will already contain Adobe AIR. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: for iOS you need to publish your app for mobile devices. for OSx you need to install Abobe AIR.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu my bad, this message appears only by installing on Android devices, with iOS is everythink ok.

Comment: Then please update your question. As for Android you can use "capptive runtime" which will embed the AIR into your app. I suggest you google about it. It is just a check mark you neet to set when exporting your APK